USB connection to Zebra printer in C#
I've been tasked with establishing a USB connection which I can use to send and receive data. More specifically, I need to send ZPL commands to a Zebra Label Printer ZD421 and the whole process needs to be done in C#.
I looked at around 10 different stackoverflow questions, which sadly did not help me much.
I first tried searching if an out of the box solution exists.
I tried the following nugets:
Zebra.Printer.Sdk, LibUsbDotNet, Usb.Net
The newest update from Zebra uses MAUI, which is not compatible with my other projects.
The 2.14 updates are too old and thus also not compatible. The 2.15 versions have the wrong docs, but through the Class View in Visual Studio I saw that there is no UsbDiscoverer.
LibUsbDotNet simply did not want to work, even though I looked at working examples, I did not get it to work.
Usb.Net is what I imagine could probably work? But I think I'm missing something. I tried looking through the documentation but I was none the wiser.
I wanted to create an UsbDevice like this:
GetUsbInterfaceManager getUsbInterfaceManager = null;
CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
IUsbInterfaceManager usbInterfaceManager = await getUsbInterfaceManager(comm.SelectedPrinterDevice.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString(), cancellationToken);
UsbDevice usbDevice = new UsbDevice(comm.SelectedPrinterDevice.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString(), (IUsbInterfaceManager)usbInterfaceManager);

But this is obviously wrong, because getUsbInterfaceManager is still null at line 3. I still don't know how to instantiate a GetUsbInterfaceManager. But I believe as it is a delegate, I need to implement it myself? Apparently I need that to get the IUsbInterfaceManager?
Apparently the Usb.Net docs are also out of date and I'm more confused by the minute it seems.
The only thing that worked at all was the System.Management, with which I was able to list all Zebra Printers that are currently connected.
I'd appreciate any help a lot.

Please add the model number of the printer to your post.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803821/zebra-printer-c-sharp-code-to-print-barcode-label

Why are you not just simply using the printer API from Windows itself!?

@user246821 that looked informative, but I did not quite wanted to reinvent the wheel. I wanted to search for a simple solution, which did not exist. So I just settled with newest nuget from zebra, which forces me to use target framework net8.0-windows10.0.1904.

@DelphiCoder I didn't look at that, but I would guess that this API does not help me manage USB connection easily or atleast it's not possible with a single line of code.

@Maynority you don't have to manage the connection at all, that's the job of the OS. You just print something using this or that printer. Why do you want to do that?

@DelphiCoder well then it seems I got something wrong? I'm not quite sure now. To even communicate with another device, you need a certain connection or not? I have USBConnection object which I got from the new Zebra Printer nuget. That object helps me easily manage printer state as well as gives me handy pre prepared commands which I can use to communicate with the printer, but also gives me the option to send raw ZPL. I'm not sure how it works with the API from Windows itself, do you have experience with that? Is it comparibly easy to what I jsut tried to describe?

@Maynority First, what is your real goal? Normally one does just send ZPL to the printer to print labels.
